# In Apple's 'TaggedLocations' Core Data example a ivar NSManagedObjectContext gets a value but I can't find where?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In Apple's Core Data example 'TaggedLocations' they have a ViewController that declares this in the header

```
@property (nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Then in the main file they never set that context equal to anything or initialize it or allocate it anywhere. They simply use it in a fetch request to retrieve results. This makes sense given that the context is simply a "scratchpad' for objects from the persistent store.

However, I don't see how they're declaring which or any persistent store either. In previous Core Data examples I've always seen people create instances of AppDelegate and access it's context and store, which makes sense because in this example the entire core data stack is there.

This is the snippet of code from Apple's example, what am I over looking?

```
/*
 Fetch existing events.
 Create a fetch request for the Event entity; add a sort descriptor; then execute the fetch.
 */
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"APLEvent"];
[request setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Order the events by creation date, most recent first.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Execute the fetch.

//Not sure how they're excuting a fetch request on self.managedObjectContext? Seems to be a nil unintialized context
//TO-DO Test value of context
NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (fetchResults == nil) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

Link to Apple's example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TaggedLocations/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008914

Thanks ahead for any input!

Comment: Check into AppDelegate ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever project created with core data , In app delegate u can get these,

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

and you can get external file too, where your data going to store.

Comment: Right, I see those in App Delegate, but how are they accessing it through this view controller? Is it because the fetch request has the entity name we're looking for and since there is only one model in this project it knows where to look automatically? Still a little puzzled. Also, I don't see the external file?

Comment: Found it! In App Delegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method they set the View Controllers managedObjectContext to the same one as the AppDelegate, that's how they do it. 'APLEventsTableViewController *controller = (APLEventsTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;'